# Xamarin offline document viewer

Tags: c#, pdf-viewer

I am looking to view multiple types of documents in a Xamarin application. I have tried the WebView control but it uses the internet to view the documents. I'm looking for a solution that works offline.

Requirements:

- .NET Xamarin (android / ios) compatible
- Accessible via Nuget
- offline access (no internet)
- PDF / Office documents / images
- streamlined UX
- Multipage scrolling / layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LEADTOOLS Xamarin SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/xamarin) contains a powerful [Document Viewer module](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-viewer-dotnet). (Disclaimer: I’m an employee of the vendor’s).

I believe it meets your listed requirements, but it would be better if you try it yourself. You can either [download full SDK’s evaluation edition setup here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main) or visit [the Xamarin Document Viewer NuGet page here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads/nuget?nuget_package=Leadtools.Document.Viewer.Xamarin)

If you download the full evaluation setup, it includes the source code of a document viewer demo inside this folder:
C:\LEADTOOLS21\Examples\Xamarin\DocumentViewerDemo

This is what the demo looks like in action:

[image: Document Viewer App]

During evaluation (and after purchasing), the SDK has free tech support through email and online chat, so feel free to send any questions you might have about the viewer to support@leadtools.com.